What is the OpenAI Chat Completion API tools/functions property format?
Is there any clear documentation on the format of OpenAI's Chat Completion API tools/functions object format? I understand it's JSON, but there appear to be underlying requirements of what property names/types are allowed inside of the objects.
I tried figuring out what all property types OpenAI allowed in their tools/functions definition, but their documentation isn't great (they just have links to a simple example and an explanation of JSON schema ). They define description and name, but leave parameters pretty much open to interpretation.
Image of tools property definition

After an hour or two of searching around, experimenting, and cobbling something together, I think I finally created a template that I could reference in the future. Hopefully this saves someone else some time in the future.
{
  "description": "This is a template that you can start from to build your tool",
  "name": "new_tool",
  "parameters": {
    "properties": {
      "array_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns an array of items (can be any type mentioned below, including an object)",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": "array"
      },
      "boolean_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns a boolean",
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "enum_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns a value from a list of enums (can be any type)",
        "enum": [
          "option 1",
          "option 2",
          "option 3"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      },
      "number_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns a number",
        "type": "number"
      },
      "object_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns an object",
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "description": "A property on the object called 'foo' that returns a string",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "bar": {
            "description": "A property on the object called 'bar' that returns a number",
            "type": "number"
          }
        }
      },
      "string_property_name": {
        "description": "A property that returns a string",
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "array_property_name",
      "number_property_name"
    ],
    "type": "object"
  }
}

